# Perl command line arguments

Tags: perl

I'm not sure how to go about processing command line arguments in Perl and was hoping someone could point my in the right direction.

My script will take arguments like this:

```
$perl my_script.pl server1_life=2 server1_ts=Ts server2_life=2 server2_ts=Age
```

The script needs to be able to extract the 'life' and timestamp values for each server. Currently I am storing the arguments in an array.

What is a good way to extract arguments in this format?

Comment: Command line arguments get put into `@ARGV` in Perl, so just process that array.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to have that particular syntax, I would recommend using (something like) [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long), and have it `--server1-life 2`, etc.

Comment: You can fetch it via @ARGV .

Comment: If you can change the syntax to be closer to unix-style dashes/double-dashes then Getopt::Long is a heavily used standard: http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html - in addition there are modules which will turn pod into command-line help/man pages, making the script behave like many other utilities with little effort.

Comment: The usual way to pass in parameters is either as `--options` or as plain positional parameters. You syntax looks like `dd` which was allegedly designed that way as an in-joke about syntax on big iron in the early 1970s -- not a very good model.

Answer (score 4):

Well, one can always parse the arguments manually. Here, we want to split each argument at `=` and probably store the results in a hash:

```
my %server_configs = map { split /=/, $_, 2 } @ARGV;
#=> (
#    server1_life => 2,
#    server1_ts   => "Ts",
#    server2_life => 2,
#    server2_ts   => "Age",
#   )
```

However, argument handling should usually be done with the `Getopt::Long` module:

```
use Getopt::Long;

my %args;
GetOptions(\%args, 'life=i@', 'ts=s@');

# combine the config parts for each server
my @server_configs = map { [$args{ts}[$_], $args{life}[$_]] } 0 .. $#{ $args{ts} };
#=> ( [Ts => 2], [Age => 2] )

# or:
my %server_configs;
@server_configs{@{ $args{ts} }} = @{ $args{life} };
#=> (Ts => 2, Age => 2)
```

E.g. invoked as `script.pl --ts=Ts --life=2 --ts=Age --life=2`

Comment: This looks roughly what I'm looking for, the difficulty I'm having is that the details extracted from each server have to be built into a MySQL command for each table (called server).

Comment: For some reason perl doesn't like the [$i] in the map, it says it has to be declared as a global variable, however this i only really denotes that the value is an integer? right?

Comment: @Caledonia91 (`$i` bug fixed) But anyway, building an SQL query has nothing to do with command-line argument parsing. You may be looking for the [DBI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) instead, with which you can `prepare` and `execute` SQL queries.

Comment: Yes I'm using this in conjunction with DBI, since the arguments I retrieve from the command line are going to be built into an SQL function (using DBI).